# Chain rule in relative rate of change?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, related-rates

If I find the relative rate of change for

$y=x^4$

when $x,y$ are differentiable functions of $t$, I will get

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y
}{\mathrm{d} t}
= \frac{\mathrm{d} (x^4)
}{\mathrm{d} t}
=4x^3 \frac{\mathrm{d} x
}{\mathrm{d} t}$

I'm confused about the $\frac{\mathrm{d} x
}{\mathrm{d} t}$ part.

If, for example, $sin(x)$ is a function of $x$ then finding $\frac{\mathrm{d} (sin(x))
}{\mathrm{d} x}$ equals to $cos(x)\frac{\mathrm{d} x
}{\mathrm{d} x}$ which equals to $cos(x)$

And in $y=x^4$ if $x$ is a function of $t$, then why doesn't

$\frac{\mathrm{d} x^4
}{\mathrm{d} t} = 4x^3 \frac{\mathrm{d} t
}{\mathrm{d} t} $?

Comment: The $x'(t)$ might be easier to reason out if you write $f(x(t))$ instead of $[x(t)]^4$, where $f(x)=x^4$. The chain rule then implies that $y'(t)=f'(x(t))x'(t)$, which is equivalent to $y'(t)=4[x(t)]^3 x'(t)$.

Comment: Maybe it might help to actually consider examples where $x$ is an explicit function of $t$, for example, you might want to compare $\frac{\text{d}x^4}{\text{d} t}$ with $4 x^3 \frac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}t}$ and $4x^3\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}$ when $x = t^2$. Also note that in your example with $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ there is no composition of functions to be considered when taking the derivative with respect to $x$. However, if $x$ were a function of $t$ and you were to consider $\frac{\text{d} \sin(x)}{\text{d} t}$, then you would also get a factor of $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}$.

Answer (score 3):

From the chain rule, we have:
$$\frac {du}{dt}=\frac {du}{dv} \cdot \frac {dv}{dt}$$
Hence, $$\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac {d(x^4)}{dt}=\frac {d(x^4)}{dx} \cdot \frac {dx}{dt}=4x^3 \frac {dx}{dt}$$

In the case of $\frac {d(\sin x)}{dx}=\cos x$, chain rule need not be applied, and even if it is, will yield the same result since $\frac {dx}{dx}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

> If, for example, $sin(x)$ is a function of $x$ then finding $\frac{\mathrm{d} (sin(x))}{\mathrm{d} x}$ equals to $cos(x)\frac{\mathrm{d} x
> }{\mathrm{d} x}$ which equals to $cos(x)$

Sure, but that is differentiating with respect to $x$; instead consider that when $x$ is a function of $t$, then differentiating with respect to $t$ gives us:$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d\sin(x) }{\mathrm d t}&=\dfrac{\mathrm d \sin(x)}{\mathrm d x}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}\\[1ex]&= \cos(x)\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

For example, let $y=x^4, x=t^2$. Then:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}=\\
4x^3\cdot 2t=4(t^2)^3\cdot 2t=8t^7$$
To verify:
$$y=x^4=(t^2)^4=t^8 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dt}=8t^7.$$